# Can I retrieve a Windows CE 6.0 image from a hardware device?

Tags: windows-ce

Is there a way to retrieve a Windows CE 6.0 image from a working hardware device that uses Windows CE?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the kind of device you are using.
Many x86-based devices boot from HD/CF/SSD/SD devices that are formatted as regular media devices. You can connect them from a PC and you may be able to find the boot image (you may use nk.bin or a compressed format).
But this is true only if the OEM did not put in place some measures to prevent you from doing that.
For devices that boot from flash accessing their contents is more complicated and, in any case, device specific. Some devices can boot in a different way, allowing you to load a firmware that is commonly used to update images, sometimes it can also recover the existing one, but it's not granted.
Taken for granted that you are trying to do that for legally acceptable reasons, if you can provide a "bigger picture" description of why you need to do that, you may find alternative ways to solve your problem.